# AngularJS Modules not working

Tags: angularjs, module

Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="groceryListApp">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<link  href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-controller="HomeController">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="color: #5bdb46">
                </span>
                {{appTitle}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>  

<div class="container" ng-controller="GroceryListItemsController">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li ng-repeat="items in groceryListItems | orderBy: 'date'" class="list-group-item-text-center clearfix">
                <span style="font-weight: bold">{{item.itemName | uppercase}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module ("groceryListApp", []);

app.controller("HomeController",["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.appTitle = "Grocery List";

}]);

app.controller("GroceryListItemsController", ["$scope", function($scope){

    $scope.groceryItems = [

        {completed: true, itemName: 'milk', date:'2017-10-01'},
        {completed: true, itemName: 'cookies', date:'2017-10-02'},
        {completed: true, itemName: 'ice cream',date:'2017-10-03'}.
        {completed: true, itemName: 'potatoes', date:'2017-10-04'}
        {completed: true, itemName: 'cereal', date:'2017-10-05'},
        {completed: true, itemName: 'bread', date:'2017-10-06'},
        {completed: true, itemName: 'eggs', date:'2017-10-07'},
        {completed: true, itemName: 'tortillas',date:'2017-10-08'}
]

}]);
```

when opening the html file with chrome, the output comes as

> {{appTitle}}
>
> {{item.itemName | uppercase}}

The controllers arent working here?

I have used boostrap version-v3.3.4
and the angular is of the latest version.

Please do tell me what I should do.

Thanks

Comment: load your angular scripts at top but not at bottom

Comment: Are you opening html file directly into browser or using any server for this?

Comment: directly from the browser

Answer (score 4):

**`script type`** should be **`script src`** , Change

**From**

```
<script type="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="js/app.js"></script>
```

**To**

```
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes the {{appTitle}} is replaced with grocery list however the{{item.itemName | uppercase}} as disappeared and the items are not visible

Comment: @Ashley that is happening because you have applied ng-controller over body so it does not take the second controller

Comment: Nice observation 

Comment: @Sajeetharan not sure about that, but the items werent displaying before as the ng repeat data was incorrect.It should be "item in groceryItems" along with script src instead of script type :P